# How can I disable my global.asax Application_Error sub when running on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-asax

As the title says, I'm trying to avoid errors being handled by the global.asax page while im debugging, while still handling them once deployed to the website.

The easy option is to just comment out the sub while we're debugging, but after the 5th time someone forgot to undo that before copying out, I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: You could add static bool variable from config file and handle error depending on this. Second option use special directives of debug #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for that purpose

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #if DEBUG
     var httpContext = ((Application)sender).Context;
     httpContext.ClearError();
     httpContext.Response.Clear();
     httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
     httpContext.Server.TransferRequest(yourUrl, true);
    #else
     your code to handle error;
    #endif
}
```